# Store activity in Fragment's onAttach(Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to invoke some functions of Activity in fragment. For convenience I'm planning to store the activity that is passed in `onAttach(Activity activity)` as a Fragment class member.

I know that `getActivity()` can also do the same work. I'm new to Android and wondering if it's bad practice. Some code likes:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyActivity mActivity;

    public void onAttach (Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = (MyActivity) activity;
    }
}
```

Please advice if I should proceed in this way. Kindly let me know the shortcomings of this approach as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, as `getActivity()` can do the same work, I think it's not a good practice to store the `MyActivity` as a private member of Fragment.

There are some reasons:

1. Fragment is designed to make a flexible UI, and may share between
   different activities. Hard-coding activity class will harm the
   reusability.
2. If you want to call some activity functions later, you can define a interface `MyInterface` containing all necessary functions. Then
   make `MyActivity` implements `MyInterface` and store `MyInterface`
   as fragment member instead, just as Android tutorial: 
   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
3. More important, the fragment implementation of Android contains `FragmentActivity mActivity`, so duplicate mActivity definition may
   cause potential problems. Just check: 
   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#Fragment